# SSRS Cumulative Running Values

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, tfs, ssrs-2008

So I am attempting to reorganize a report I put together. I had the running totals working before the redesign, but I have been pouring over this for a day and can't figure out why it is no longer functioning as I had thought.

The sum values are correct here, but it keeps accumulating them and not spreading them out over the area paths I've defined (which are populating obviously).

I have the sprint and area name linked in a hierarchy for the row groups then followed by this expression:

[image]

```
 =RunningValue(Fields!Sev_1_Count.Value, SUM, "RowGroup")
```

Each column after the area name is defining a severity level of defects, just for context. The Sev_1_Count expression should take the count of all defects in this severity level then spread them across their associated area names. Which worked in the previous version... I just can't for the life of me figure why it won't work now. Thoughts?

[image]

Comment: Your scope should be `IterationName1`

Comment: No, the 60 value is incorrect, the values currently shown ARE the cumulative values for that severity level overall. By linking them to IterationName 1 it just shows the addition for each one.

Comment: I cant follow what you are trying to achieve.  Post your expected results.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you're applying the running total to each field. It seems that wherever you're putting

```
RunningValue(Fields!Sev_1_Count.Value, SUM, "RowGroup")
```

you should just have

```
Fields!Sev_1_Count.Value
```

instead. As you need totals on both sides, you should have a matrix and the right and bottom rows of you columns should be outside the group "Iteration Name" with a value of

```
sum(Fields!Sev_1_Count.Value).
```

Not sure what I'm missing. Maybe your original dataset is set up in a way where you can't do that?

Your row groups should be grouped on name and your column groups should be grouped on severity level.

I'm not sure what you mean by your comment below Randy, but the best practice for something like this would be to have a data-set that consists of 3 fields:
"EnvironmentName", "DefectCount" and "SeverityLevel". Then in your matrix, you have the DefectCount as your Details, EnvironmentName as your RowGroup and SeverityLevel as your ColumnGroup. Then the right column and bottom row are placed outside the groups and have the value of Sum(DefectCount). Anything outside of that seems like an over-complication.

It seems like you want to use running total to add the columns for severity levels if i'm not mistaken? then you shouldn't be grouping them on rows. Instead of the "RowGroup" scope, maybe you should try None. Good luck.

Comment: So the gist of my reorganization was to have this report add all the environment options that now exist. So I created a bunch of fields that would calculate values withing each specific environment. I didn't change any of the ones used in this table, this is the cause of my frustration.